# How can bind StrokeDashArray property in MVVM pattern wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have WPF application where I have in one canvas some lines to be need to be dotted line, and some is need to be normal line. My question is what exactly type is StrokeDashArray . In msdn I see is use DoubleCollection but is from  System.Windows.Media. 
How can make property for StrokeDashArray used good practice in MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to the dash array then it's a DoubleCollection, so you do something like this:

```
    private DoubleCollection _Dashes = new DoubleCollection { 1, 2 };
    public DoubleCollection Dashes
    {
        get { return this._Dashes;}
        set { this._Dashes = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

And then in XAML:

```
    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="{Binding Dashes}" X1="0" Y1="50" X2="100" Y2="50"/>
```

If you're creating a dynamic array of Canvas elements then you'll need to create an ItemsControl and set ItemsControl.Panel to be a Canvas. Then you'll usually use Item.Template to declare the line for each element along with a Style that chooses between your different line/dash types using Data Triggers.

Comment: Is good practice to use DoubleCollection, because is in namespace System.Windows.Media who is in assembly PresentationCore.dll

Comment: If you don't want to use DoubleCollection then it's easy enough to use a converter to create one from double[] or whatever else you want to use.